# Cycling through a list until I find the correct sequence?

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I need to cycle through a list in Prolog until a valid sequence appears. In this case the sequence goes `"u" "r" "d" "l"`. The lists will only be made up of those characters. I already have a method that returns a list of all possible cycles, such as this:

```
?- all_cases(["l", "u", "r", "d"], S).
S = [["l", "u", "r", "d"], ["u", "r", "d", "l"], ["r", "d", "l", "u"], ["d", "l", "u", "r"]].
```

As you can see, the second list is in the order I need. Now the problem is, I need to traverse that list (S) until I locate the one I need. The final result should look like this. 'Cyclic shift' is the correct output, and 'What' contains all of the shifts.

```
 all_cases(["u","r","r","d","d","l","l","u"],What),try_all_sqA(What).
 cyclic shift: ["u","u","r","r","d","d","l","l"] is correct
 What = [["u", "r", "r", "d", "d", "l", "l", "u"], ["r", "r", "d", "d", "l", "l", "u"|...], ["r", "d", "d", "l", "l", "u"|...], ["d", "d", "l", "l", "u"|...], ["d", "l", "l", "u"|...], ["l", "l", "u"|...], ["l", "u"|...]["u"|...]].
```

I've already tried [sort/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/4), but that only gives me the list in alphabetical or reverse alphabetical order, and I need to sort it based on the unique sequence (u, r, d, l).

Comment: But here `What` is unified with all "rotations" if I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, what has all rotations

Comment: but later in your question, you write "and 'What' is the rest of the shifts.".

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let us split the problem in smaller parts. We will first construct a predicate that matches with elements of a list, until the list is exhausted, or until it reaches an element that is no longer the item we are looking for, we can implement this with a `seq/3` predicate:

```
seq([], _, []).
seq([H|T], H, R) :-
    seq(T, H, R).
seq([H|T], X, [H|T]) :-
    dif(H, X).
```

For example:

```
?- seq(["u", "r", "d", "l"], "u", R).
R = ["r", "d", "l"] ;
false.

?- seq(["u", "r", "d", "l"], "r", R).
R = ["u", "r", "d", "l"].
```

That means that we can validate that a sequence has zero or more `"u"`s, followed by zero or more `"r"`s, followed by zero or more `"d"`s, and finally followed by zero or more `"l"`s with:

```
sequrdl(LA) :-
    seq(LA, "u", LB),
    seq(LB, "r", LC),
    seq(LC, "d", LD),
    seq(LD, "l", []).
```

For example:

```
?- sequrdl(["u","u","r","r","d","d","l","l"]).
true ;
false.

?- sequrdl(["u","u","r","r","d","d","l","l", "u"]).
false.

?- sequrdl(["u","u","r","r","d","d"]).
true ;
false.
```

So now we only need to search until we find a rotated list for which this holds, and then we can print that list, like:

```
try_all_sqA(What) :-
    member(SubList, What),
    sequrdl(SubList),
    print('cyclic shift: '),
    print(SubList),
    nl.
```

For example:

```
?- try_all_sqA([["l", "u", "r", "d"], ["u", "r", "d", "l"], ["r", "d", "l", "u"], ["d", "l", "u", "r"]]).
'cyclic shift: '["u","r","d","l"]
true ;
false.
```

Comment: You are truly some kind of wizard. Thank you!